# Background Change to Css with thumbnail in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

good day.... is there a way to change the background image of div while using Slick.Js ? say for example, if i press one of the image thumbnail, the background of div would change. so far my code is not reliable when it comes for example different image sizes

im not sure how to change the background image of div if i press each images in the slick carousel

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider-for').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.thumbnails'
  });
  $('.thumbnails').slick({
    slidesToShow: 9,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.slid {
  width: 100%;
}

.thumbnail-img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-for {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.thumbnails {
  margin-top: -300px;
}

.cc {
  position: relative;
}

.slider-for {
  position: absolute;
}

.some {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
}


/** HEADER **/

.banner-img {
  background-size: fill;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1020px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  width: 1440px;
}

.navbar {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.navbar a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  float: left !important;
}

.navlink {
  float: right;
}

.navlink li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
  list-style: none;
}

.hero-text {
  margin-top: 100px;
  float: left !important;
}

.hero-text h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.hero-text h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.hero-text p {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!-- slick slider-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" />

<div class="slid">
  <div class="slider3">
    <div class="cc">
      <div class="some">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar">
              <div class="logo">
                <h3>B2B DESIGN</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="navlink">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container hero-text">
              <h1>Unlimited Lorem for <br>unlimited ipsume</h1>
              <h2>& Fusce feugiat congue ipsum</h2>
              <p>Ut vel orci sem. Morbi quis diam ac ligula ultricies <br>Ut eget massa ornare, porta elit quis, porttitor leo. Nulla facilisi. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- container -->
        </div>
        <!-- end header -->
      </div>
      <!-- some-->



      <div class="slider-for">
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/En-d0nPWMAIXYQk.jpg:large" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://sepidehirvani.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/green-nature-dual-monitor-other-1-2000x1024.jpg" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://tz-mag-media.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/26144641/image101.jpg" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/91/24/0f/91240f62852bedc0f49d344389ae7097.jpg" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://journeysbydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/cropBalade_en_pirogue_canoe-rambling_Iharana-Bush-Camp-1-2000x1024.jpg" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://journeysbydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1_K30D454AF2827C_44-1-2000x1024.jpg" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://bokun.s3.amazonaws.com/d397bd70-f43c-4b8f-a04a-feff5ab3ddf9.jpeg?w=247&h=200&fit=crop" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://i1.wp.com/www.climatechangetheatreaction.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/b40a592b47cea301d5e70906d4a86562-e1570158663199.jpg?resize=2000%2C1024" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://journeysbydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/cropBat-Forest_BBC-Hide_Aerial.jpg" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://journeysbydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/cropMasoala_Wildlife_HR11-2000x1024.jpg" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/tourhound/tours/3726999a-490b-476b-9722-e56a839613f6/crop2016-GP-ODL-ALH-220-2000x1024.jpg" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://wineandcountrylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/PoolhouseINT_wide-5239_originalLead.jpg" loading="lazy">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="banner-img" src="https://www.danacommunications.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/kigr-lrg.jpg" loading="lazy">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- slider-for -->
    </div>

    <div class="thumbnails">
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/En-d0nPWMAIXYQk.jpg:large" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://sepidehirvani.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/green-nature-dual-monitor-other-1-2000x1024.jpg" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/91/24/0f/91240f62852bedc0f49d344389ae7097.jpg" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://journeysbydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/cropBalade_en_pirogue_canoe-rambling_Iharana-Bush-Camp-1-2000x1024.jpg" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://journeysbydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1_K30D454AF2827C_44-1-2000x1024.jpg" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://bokun.s3.amazonaws.com/d397bd70-f43c-4b8f-a04a-feff5ab3ddf9.jpeg?w=247&h=200&fit=crop" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://i1.wp.com/www.climatechangetheatreaction.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/b40a592b47cea301d5e70906d4a86562-e1570158663199.jpg?resize=2000%2C1024" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://journeysbydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/cropBat-Forest_BBC-Hide_Aerial.jpg" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://journeysbydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/cropMasoala_Wildlife_HR11-2000x1024.jpg" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/tourhound/tours/3726999a-490b-476b-9722-e56a839613f6/crop2016-GP-ODL-ALH-220-2000x1024.jpg" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://wineandcountrylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/PoolhouseINT_wide-5239_originalLead.jpg" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://www.danacommunications.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/kigr-lrg.jpg" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-wraps">
        <img class="thumbnail-img" src="https://www.danacommunications.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/kigr-lrg.jpg" loading="lazy" width="210" height="224">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- thumbnails -->
  </div>
  <!-- slider 3-->
</div>
<!--slid-->


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Put your code in a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, it's already working, though it's an image tag and not a background.

The problem is because the header (*cf. `.some`*) is in front of your carrousel. You end up not being able to click on the elements, so if you remove the `z-index` rule from:

```
.some {
  /* z-index: 9999; */
  position: absolute;
}
```

It'll work as expected.

However, you'll have to remake your HTML structure to get both your texts and the functionality. Or at least change some CSS rules, but it can end to get pretty hacky.

Comment: i see. i was looking for a clean way by using js. thanks!